# Is there annotation for json-b that works like @JsonValue

Tags: java, json, spring, jsonb

I'm having a trouble with deserializing JSON like:

```
[{
    "foo": "bar",
    "example": "value"
}]
```

For some reason, API I use packs it in unnamed Array with one element. I'm accessing that API with RestController.

As long as I used default Jackson Converter, I could easily prepare model classes like that (getters, setters, constructors omitted for clarity):

```
public class Model {

    private String foo;
    private String example;

}

public class Response {

    @JsonValue
    private List<Model> model;

}
```

Repository class

```
public class FooRepository {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String getFoo() {
        ResponseEntity<Response> response =
            restTemplate
                .exchange("http://localhost:8080/api"
                         HttpMethod.GET,
                         new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()),
                         Response.class);

        return response.getBody().getModel().get(0).getFoo();
    }
```

I cannot find any annotation that works like @JsonValue for Jsonb. Is there one? Or maybe there is another way to fix my problem without using Jackson?

edit:
I figured out a workaround solution.

```
    public String getFoo() {
        ResponseEntity<List<Model>> response =
            restTemplate
                .exchange("http://localhost:8080/api"
                         HttpMethod.GET,
                         new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()),
                         ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Model>>());

        return response.getBody().get(0).getFoo();
    }
```